# How do I remove the ServerSignature added by mod_fcgid?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security, mod-fcgid

I'm running Mod_Security and I'm using the SecServerSignature to customize the `Server` header that Apache returns. This part works fine, however I'm also running mod_fcgid which appends "mod_fcgid/2.3.5" to the header.

Is there any way I can turn this off? Setting `ServerSignature off` doesn't do anything. I was able to get it to go away by changing the `ServerTokens` but that removed the customization I had added.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ServerTokens` in a config file.

ServerTokens

This directive configures what you return as the Server HTTP response
Header. The default is 'Full' which sends information about the OS-Type
and compiled in modules.

Set to one of:  `Full` | `OS` | `Minor` | `Minimal` | `Major` | `Prod`
where `Full` conveys the most information, and `Prod` the least.

I suggest to set it to `Prod`, then they will only see that you are using `Apache Server at domain.com Port 80`.

Don't forget to restart/reload the Apache config files!

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens

Answer (score 0):

`ServerTokens` is what manipulates the `Server` response header.  (`ServerSignature` is used for server generated documents.)

However, if you want to completely control the `Server` header I would suggest using the `Header` option:

```
Header set Server "Apache/2 my_customizations"
```

as an example.

Comment: hmmm... That doesn't seem to work. I don't think Apache allows you to override the server header that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reorder the module loading in Apache so mod_security loads after mod_fcgi.

Read the "Server identity masking" section of the mod_security docs.
http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/06-special_features.html

Two notes: Mod_security will show the real server signature in the error_log which will be different than the one given to the public.

Second, the document also explains that SecServerSignature directive only works with ServerTokens set to "Full"

Mark

Comment: I've tried loading the module first and last, and it doesn't make a difference. I also doubled checked and ServerTokens are set to "Full" and the problem is in the actual response header not just the logs. Thanks

Comment: I'm not a great coder, but I did not see anything in the most recent version of mod_fcgi that would place an entry in the server description.  What version are you running?